# How to set different css attributes with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set for each of input fields different z-index values. How I can do this with JQuery?

I want something like this:

```
   jQuery.each($("input[type=text]"), function (index, item) {

        item.css("z-index", index);
    });
```

But "item" has no css property. How to correctly iterate an array ?

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="Text4" placeholder="Some text"
    runat="server" />
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="Text5" placeholder="Some text"
    runat="server" />
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="Text6" placeholder="Some text"
    runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery.ready is too late: How do I apply CSS Values with JQuery before Rendering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725753/jquery-ready-is-too-late-how-do-i-apply-css-values-with-jquery-before-rendering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` in your code returns HTML element, not jQuery object.

I would suggest you to change your code to:

```
$("input[type=text]").each( function (index, item) {
    $( item ).css("z-index", index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the CSS property value:

```
$(selector).css(property)
```

Set the CSS property and value:

```
$(selector).css(property,value)
```

Set CSS property and value using a function:

```
$(selector).css(property,function(index,currentvalue))
```

Set multiple properties and values:

```
$(selector).css({property:value, property:value, ...})
```